# text-orientation in class doesn't apply to tr

Tags: php, css, class

i need to show one row's words vertically, for that i've created a class in my stylesheet containing text-orientation:sideways then applied it on the tr , but it won't seem to work, i'm a bit new to CSS so maybe someone could help please

this it the table row

```
 echo "<tr class='vert'>";
```

and this is the stylesheet

```
 table  tr.vert{

    text-orientation: sideways;

}
```

Comment: Do this `echo "<tr class='vert'>";` and check Add single quotes around class name

Comment: you can only have `td` elements as children of `tr` - the cell should have sufficient height

Comment: i've tried the single quotes but it didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be missing the `writing-mode` property..

> The text-orientation CSS property sets the orientation of the text characters in a line. It only affects text in vertical mode (when writing-mode is not horizontal-tb). It is useful for controlling the display of languages that use vertical script, and also for making vertical table headers.
>
> [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-orientation)

```css
span {
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  text-orientation:sideways;
}
```

```html
<span>Writing Mode</span>
```